# Why Adaptive Autosar ECU use only Ethernet Switch for connection and why not Ethernet Port directly

Tags: ethernet, autosar

I have recently come across **Adaptive AutoSAR**, I see all the Domain Controller/ECUs on the Adaptive side uses Ethernet Switch port to connect to other ECUs or Gateways. I know Switch has many features, but Could you please explain
**1.** Can we use inbuilt Ethernet Ports for doing the same functionality. or
**2.** What can the Switch provide which Ethernet Port doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike CAN and other communication interfaces, SOC could not direct connect by Ethernet port interfaces. A second-layer switch should be used to be divided the network into different collision domains.